# Write To TextFile Using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

My contents are displayed in the console, but my text file is never generated.  What is keeping my text file from being generated?

```
        public static void GetDirInfo()
    {
        string filename = "C:\\Test.txt";
        string sourcePath = @"C:\";
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
        Console.WriteLine(dir);
        var children = dir.EnumerateFileSystemInfos();
        Console.WriteLine(children);
        var files = children.OfType<FileInfo>().Count();
        Console.WriteLine(files);
        var directories = children.OfType<DirectoryInfo>().Count();
        Console.WriteLine(directories);


        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(dir);
            sw.WriteLine(children);
            sw.WriteLine(files);
            sw.WriteLine(directories);
        }
     }
```

Comment: `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` only goes thru once.

Comment: @DanielA.White -> but the data is written to the console window appropriately before the tstreamwriter loop is hit?

Comment: Not a good idea trying to write a file in the root of your system drive. You should get an exception like "Access denied"

Comment: @TimmyTurner yea thats consuming the list, before the writer can use it

Comment: @DanielA.White - so I need to re-write the recursion method since EnumerateFileSystemInfos is what is causing the issue!

Comment: It's crashing for me with `UnauthorizedAccessException`, try different path?

Comment: @DanielA.White Every time you call GetEnumerator() on an IEnumerable<T>, you get a new enumerator. The data is not "consumed before it can be used". Every enumeration starts from scratch.

Comment: @Steve - I changed the save locatoin and still do not receive needed txt file

Comment: I have tested your code writing in a temporary folder and it works as expected. Of course the content of the file is probably not what you wish to get but this is for another time

Comment: @TimmyTurner You should be getting an exception of some kind if the file cannot be created. What is it?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - I am receiving no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running your code and got UnauthorizedAccessException. I ran the same code as an admin and the file was created.

Comment: I changed the location to C:\Test\Test.txt and still no file

Comment: @TimmyTurner Try running the program as an administrator